# Had a peculiar issue with my EC2 instance yesterday, disk space low?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I've got an asp.net core application running on Linux/Nginx in Elastic Beanstalk.  All of a sudden it stopped working properly yesterday, the issue was that one of the main javascript files was no longer being served out, instead Chrome reported a ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR.  Navigating directly to the file did work fine though, but when loading the app it self, the request to the file always failed with this error.

I tried different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Vivaldi), different devices (PC, mobile phone) and different network connections (LAN/WIFI/Mobile data) but the result was the same everywhere.

Googling the issue gave the impression that this error can be caused by multiple different things.  After some more digging and examining the network logs in Chrome, the actual error suggested that the server was probably the issue - it was terminating the connection before all the file had been sent (something related to HTTP/2).  Some more Googling and everything suggested that this was because of low diskspace on the server (Linux/Nginx) and when diskspace is low or completely exhausted, Nginx would sometimes do this.

I never received any notification that the instance was running out of disk space, nor did I see it mentioned anywhere.  Some more digging and I two other issues occurred that lead me to believe that the issue was indeed related to diskspace.

When I tried to request logs from the instance in the AWS console, the log file would be generated but it was always 0 bytes in size.  When I tried to deploy a new version of my app to the instance (Using the AWS toolkit in Visual Studio) everything seemed to be successful, no errors reported anywhere, but the changes were not reflected on the instance, it appeared to be still running the older version.  When I tried to retrieve the logs to see if there was an error somewhere ... but I just got empty log files.

It wasn't until I decided to apply a recommended update to the instance (Linux 2.3.5 instead of 2.3.4) which probably resets the environment completely - that everything seemed to go back to normal, and my app is running normally again.

What. The. Hell.  Any ideas what might have been happening?  Anyone had similar issues?  I had been thinking of migrating to Azure, this incident made me want proceed with that even more.

Comment: I would be surprised if anyone who has used EC2 for a period of time has not had disk space/performance issues.  That said, if you are using a operating system platform and cannot get a memory dump for analysis, it's difficult to pursue problems like this with almost no data.

Comment: Computers and software can act a bit weird when the disk is full. I suggest you set up Cloudwatch to alert you when the disk is full. It's not difficult, but you do have to install and configure the Cloudwatch agent as free disk space is an OS metric not a hypervisor level metric. The grass isn't always greener, it sounds like this problem could happen on any host. You might like to try to work out why the disk filled - updates, etc. You can also resize the EBS volume then restart to increase disk size, with Linux at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update.  Had this happen again.  Spent some more time digging this time around.  Managed to connect to my instance via SSH to examine further.  Turns out that some logs where eating up all the diskspace.  I modified my instance and increased the root volume size and since I now have the SSH access up and running, it will be easier for me to monitor the diskspace in the future and prevent this from happening.

I find it a bit weird that you have to SSH into your instance to perform a mundane task like checking the available diskspace.  You can see all kinds of information about your ELB volume in the AWS console, but not the diskspace utilization.  Also, when you modify your volume and increase it's size, you still have to SSH in and run a couple of linux commands to increase actually be able to use the increased volume size.  I'm a bit surprised how things rapidly get extra complicated when you are performing tasks which are perhaps a bit more advanced than the really basic stuff.